# Is it possible to add UIBarButtonItem to a Segmented Control

Tags: objective-c

I want to know if it is possible to add UIBarButtons to a SegmentedControl. It compiles but gives a runtime error:

```
-[UIBarButtonItem isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4fcc0
```

Here is my code.

```
UIBarButtonItem *atolButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A to L"
      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(atol:)];

UIBarButtonItem *ltozButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"L to Z"
      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ltoz:)];

NSArray *titleButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: atolButton, ltozButton, nil];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:titleButtons];
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
[segmentedControl release];
...

- (void)atol:(id) sender {
NSLog(@"atol called");  
}

- (void)ltoz:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"ltoz called");
}
```

**I have been able to make it work with the following code**

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a to l", @"l to z", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(atol:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;

[segmentedControl release];
```

Comment: Why dont you use two UIBarButtonsItems instead of using segmented control ?

Comment: That's a possibility but wouldn't I then have to worry about the state/physical presence of the buttons i.e. manage if they are depressed etc. Seems like a lot of work. It is easier to just check the title of the segmented control and invoke the corresponding action from there. The segmented control acts like a switch.  I am just surprised that the framework doesn't automatically support a common scenario of a list of buttons. But I could be wrong... are UIBarButtonItems in a common nav aware of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UISegmentedControl` inherits from `UIControl` which inherits from `UIView`, so you can add subViews to it as you would to a UIView.

However, the segmented aspect is quite different. Each segment has an `image` property and `title` property, but that's all.

When you invoke `initWithItems:`, this must be an `NSArray` of `UIImages` or `NSStrings`.

I have no idea what you're trying to do that compels you to add buttons to a segmented controller, but I encourage you instead to set the `title` and `image` properties of the `UISegmentedController` and the customize the action in whatever method the controller is meant to trigger. For example:

```
-(void)segmentAction:(UISegmentedController *)segment {
    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self atol];
    } else {
        [self ltoz];
    }
}
```

I have no idea what you cannot accomplish this way that you wish to do.

Comment: Tx. I simply went with what felt intuitive. I saw that you could init with an array. At that point I thought it might already know that most applications would use a list of buttons. So why not pass it an array of buttons. I just wanted to know what was going on behind the scenes. It felt nice to be able to automatically have the selector associated with the button. Tx for the explanation.

Comment: @vesselhead: Be careful with that strategy. Sometimes doing something seemingly logical that conflicts with the Documentation will compile and even run, but will be grounds for rejection by Apple. They are fairly picky about how their custom elements are used. Good luck with the project!